# Mysql FOREIGN KEY error 150

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updateddate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_flag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE `alarts` (
  `alart_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alart_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `interval` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `alart_sent_counter` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `alart_types_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `contact_group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`alart_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`alart_types_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_types_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to create new table with two FOREIGN KEY like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `alart_question_mapping` (
`alart_question_mapping_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`alart_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`alart_question_mapping_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES questions(`question_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

but I am getting error:
    Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'alart_question_mapping' (errno: 150)

How can I create this table ?

Thank's.

Comment: (`alart` => `alert` ?) `REFERENCES alart_types`: where is the `alart_types` table?

Comment: yes I know but I all ready have a table with that name :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find table `alart_types`.

**[From MySQL Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. **It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys**, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.

I think you mean

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart(`alart_id`)
```

instead of

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
```

Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can see is you are referencing a table in your `CREATE TABLE` statement that is not present in what you provided:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
```

If you remove this reference the table will create. See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a3f3)

Edit #1, based on your update the problem is you are referencing the wrong field in your last table:

Change this:

```
CREATE TABLE `alart_question_mapping` (
`alart_question_mapping_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`alart_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`alart_question_mapping_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES questions(`question_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
)
```

To this:

```
CREATE TABLE `alart_question_mapping` (
`alart_question_mapping_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`alart_id` BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`alart_question_mapping_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES questions(`question_id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_types_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So you are changing this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
```

to this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_types_id`)
```

If you are referencing the `alart_types` table then you will want to reference the `alart_types_id` not the `alart_id`

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d9f4)

Answer (score 2):

Chane the statement:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
```

to

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alarts(`alart_id`)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this table

```
CREATE TABLE alart_types ( 
  alart_types_id BIGINT(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  alarts_types_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (alart_types_id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

it doesn't really make sense to have an autoincrement id number without also having a unique constraint on alarts_types_name. Without that unique constraint, you're almost certain to end up with a table whose data looks like this.

```
1  Warning
2  Critical
3  Warning
4  Warning
```

This constraint references a column that doesn't exist.

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_id`)
```

It should be

```
FOREIGN KEY (`alart_id`) REFERENCES alart_types(`alart_types_id`)
```